# Relative to which directory is quarkus.keycloak.devservices.realm-path being resolved?

Tags: quarkus

When starting Quarkus 2.7.1 with dev services enabled for KeyCloak, you can specify `quarkus.keycloak.devservices.realm-path=realm.json` in the `application.properties`.

The [documentation for this property just says](https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services#quarkus-keycloak-devservices-keycloak-keycloak-build-time-config_quarkus.keycloak.devservices.realm-path):

> The class or file system path to a Keycloak realm file which will be used to initialize Keycloak.

It does not clearly state relative to what base directory the path is being resolved.

There are [example projects](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/security-keycloak-authorization-quickstart) where the file is placed inside a `config/` subdir. I tried this as well as in the project's root dir. Neither location seems to work, the file is ignored and Quarkus creates a realm with its default values instead.

Specifying an absolute path works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in the classpath is searched for the path specified in the property, e.g. resources dir.

The documentation already gives a hunch: "The class or ...", so at very least the classpath must be searched.

In the linked example project, in the maven pom the [resources are extended](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/f3f4939df30bcff062be126faaaeb58cb7c79fb6/security-keycloak-authorization-quickstart/pom.xml#L68-L74) to also include `config`, therefore it works there.